# Remove gap between tables placed side by side

Tags: html

I have several tables, placed side by side. I need to remove the gap between them. How can I do that?

[What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOQhh.png)

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div th:each="group:${groups}" th:if="${groups.size()>0}" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0" th:style="'width:'+ ${90/groups.size()}+'%;'">
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: solid black 1px; width: 100%; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        test
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 10%; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0">
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: solid black 1px; width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <form action="/groups/save/" method="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="null">
                            <input type="hidden" name="title" th:value="null">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary myButton" type="submit">
                                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/plus-math.png"/>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try adding negative margin to `margin-left`.

Comment: do you mean to the tables? It does not work

Comment: You can add to the tables, but I recommend you to add it to parent div, so there would not be any inconsistencies in the position. For ex: for the 1st table,  you can add -ve margin to this div `<div th:each="group:${groups}"...>`